# java class and static method

Tags: java, class

I have a question regarding how to use variables that I have already used in a method into another method and how to set a limit on what a user can input, for example, for one of my java homework assignments I need to write a program that takes 3 to 6 names and then I need to create a new static method called geneateNewName() and it has to use the 3 to 6 names to display the names as well as take each of the names' second letter and produce a new name, how can I do this, thank you. Also, here is the code that I have so far:

```
public class Testing{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Console c = System.console();
        String str1;
        String str2;
        String str3;
        String str4;
        String str5;
        String str6;
        str1 = c.readLine("Please enter a family member's name: ");
        str2 = c.readLine("Please enter a family member's name: ");
        str3 = c.readLine("Please enter a family member's name: ");
        str4 = c.readLine("Please enter a family member's name: ");
        str5 = c.readLine("Please enter a family member's name: ");
        str6 = c.readLine("Please enter a family member's name: ");
    }

    public static void generateNewName(){
        System.out.println((str1.charAt(1)));
        System.out.print(str22.charAt(1));
        System.out.print(str33.charAt(1));
        System.out.print(str44.charAt(1));
        System.out.print(str55.charAt(1));
        System.out.print(str66.charAt(1));
    }
}
```

When I run this program on the command line, it only asks for six names, it doesn't display the newly generated name that is coded in the generateNewName() static method.

Comment: IMO, this won't even compile... so you cannot run it. Did you miss some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the others have said, you never call `generateNewName()` so it doesn't run. But there are much bigger problems here.

You should be using `Scanner` to read user input. You're also declaring your string variables in `main()` which limits their scope so `generateNewName()` can't see them. There are several ways you can make your strings available to `generateNewName()`, including passing in all the strings individually or storing them all in an array and passing that in. However for your purposes you can just declare all the strings as static class variables.

```
class Testing
{
    public static String str1;
    public static String str2;
    public static String str3;
    public static String str4;
    public static String str5;
    public static String str6;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a family member's name: ");
        str1 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter a family member's name: ");
        str2 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter a family member's name: ");
        str3 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter a family member's name: ");
        str4 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter a family member's name: ");
        str5 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter a family member's name: ");
        str6 = scanner.next();

        generateNewName();
    }

    public static void generateNewName()
    {
        System.out.print(str1.charAt(1));
        System.out.print(str2.charAt(1));
        System.out.print(str3.charAt(1));
        System.out.print(str4.charAt(1));
        System.out.print(str5.charAt(1));
        System.out.print(str6.charAt(1));
    }
}
```

Since I'm assuming you're still a beginner the above code will work for you just fine. But I'd like to show you how you could cut way back on the number of lines of code you have using techniques you've probably already learned or hopefully will learn very soon. By using a `for` loop and string array you don't have to write out all those lines each time you want to prompt and collect data from the user. From there you can pass the array of names to `generateNewName()` and use another `for` loop to print out your new name. Now you don't need to declare your strings individually and you can control how many times the user is prompted to provide input by simply changing the size of the array.

```
class Testing
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arraySize = 0;
        while(arraySize > 6 || arraySize < 3)
        {
            //Get user input here.
        }
        String[] names = new String[arraySize];
        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a family member's name: ");
            names[i] = scanner.next();
        }

        generateNewName(names);
    }

    public static void generateNewName(String[] names)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(names[i].charAt(1));
        }
    }
}
```

To print out the generated name on one line make sure you use `System.out.print()` and not `System.out.println()`.

Comment: The suggestions that you gave me work fine, the only thing that I also want is to be able to set a limit to how many family member's name the user can enter, which is 3 to 6, and I also want to be able to display the newly generate name as a single argument, like if a user entered the names bob, fred, and jimmy, the computer would display the newly generated name as ori and not to display each character on a new line, how can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: The method `generateNewName()` will already display the new name on a single line. As for limiting user input, you could create an integer called `arraySize` and ask the user to enter a number between 3 and 6. You can put that logic inside a `while` loop that will keep prompting the user to enter a number if the user enters a number that is not between 3 and 6. Once you have your number you can create the array using `arraySize` as the size. Use `.nextInt()` instead of `.next()` to read in integers input by the user.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to create a new method called `getArraySize()` that would return an integer and ask for the user input there. Before returning the integer you would check to see if the number is between 3 and 6. If not then recursively call `getArraySize()`. You would call the method like this: `String[] names = new String[getArraySize()];`

Comment: I am just a beginner in Java, so can you please provide an example of what you are saying. I know what a while loop is but I don't know where to put it in the program because there is already a for loop in the program, I am also fairly new to Java methods. Here is the code that I have so far:

Comment: Apologies, I don't know how to add my code here (I tried indenting 8 spaces before pasting the code and it wouldn't work) and when I ran the program, the generateNewName() would display the new name with each character on a single line, as if these characters are arguments by themselves, how can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Edit your original question at the top of the page and add it there. Don't delete your old code, just add it below it. As for printing out the new name, make sure you're using `System.out.print` and not `System.out.println`.

Comment: I have added my new code above, where do I add the while loop to set a limit on the family members' names the user can enter and how do I display the newly generated name on one line? Thank you.

Comment: See my updated answer. Please be sure to click on the check mark if my answer was helpful to you.

Comment: I have one question in regards to your updated answer, in the while loop, when it says // Get user input here., do I put anything here, because the user input is already asked in the for loop? Thank you.

Comment: You want to set how many names the user should enter, correct? Inside the `while` loop you want to prompt the user to input a value that's between 3 and 6 and assign it to `arraySize` using `scanner.nextInt()`. If the user enters a number that's not between 3 and 6 then prompt the user to try again. The `while` loop will take care of the rest.

Comment: I am a bit confused on what you are saying, may you please put it in code form? Thank you.

Comment: You have to do this part on your own. I've given you a lot already but I can't give you the whole answer. Read through my answers and you should have everything you need to finish this. You should be able to do it with one line of code using `scanner.nextInt()`.

Comment: I have one minor question, I successfully wrote the program, adding the user input in the while loop, but when I run the program in Terminal, everything works fine until the program reaches the generateNewName() method, it displays the result by putting the second letter of each name before the, I don't know what you call it, but here is an example: roi bash 3.2 $. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: After looking further into my program, when I run it, every time, it displays "Need to enter a number between 3 to 6!" even if I entered a number between 3 to 6, how can I fix this? Thank you. My modified code is displayed above.

Comment: The conditional in your `if` statement will always evaluate to `true`. Change it to `if(arraySize > 6 || arraySize < 3)`. Also you can delete the `else` statement as it isn't necessary.

Comment: I just posted a new question, may you please help me, thank you, please look above at my original question.

Answer (score 2):

You never call `generateNewName()`. You should stick it in main somewhere. if you want it to be run.

Answer (score 1):

you should call generateNewName method after the last read line like this:

```
    str6 = c.readLine("Please enter a family member's name: ");
    generateNewName();
}
```